# Dojo ajax calls don't work in IE9 Beta?

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-9

It appears that dojo xhr ajax calls don't work in IE9 beta. Has anyone else seen this behavior?

I'm using the following code to make a server-side request and return json back:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
        url: baseUrl + path,
        handleAs: 'json',
        timeout: 60000,
        content: request,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        load: function(result) { ... },
        error: function(error, args) { ... }
    });
```

This code works perfectly in IE7, IE8, Firefox, and Chrome. However in IE9 beta it gives me:

Error: xhr cancelled
LOG: debug: Error: xhr cancelled
  SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught  ?tbUsername=user&tbPassword=pass, line 118 character 1
  SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught  ?tbUsername=user&tbPassword=pass, line 118 character 1

Any tips would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: A plain old xhrPost doesn't seem to give me issues in IE9PP... anything else special about your case?  I will say though that Dojo does seem to have some issues with IE9 (e.g. related to dojo.connect and animations), and I'm not sure what version they'll end up targetting IE9 support for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the Dojo versions support IE9 so far, not even 1.6.0.  A new version, 1.6.1 is in the works that will support IE9.

In the meantime, use the "EmulateIE8" meta tag on your sites to force IE9 into IE8 standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Dojo 1.6 dropped the same day as IE9 and contains IE9 support:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.6.html

Time to upgrade Dojo ...

Comment: I don't think 1.6 supports IE9, although it does work on 1.6 somewhat.  Some sites that use dijit's will have prob.  A maintenance release (1.6.1) is in the works to support IE9.

Comment: Any idea when 1.6.1 will be made available?